# Deploying elasticsearch cluster on 3 vms

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, docker-machine, boot2docker

I created 3 VMs with docker-machine and VirtualBox and I am trying to deploy elasticseach.
I created this docker-compose:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
      - esdatavm1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esvmnet
  elasticsearch2:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    volumes:
      - esdatavm2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]
    networks:
      - esvmnet
  elasticsearch3:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch"
    volumes:
      - esdatavm3:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == worker]
    networks:
      - esvmnet
volumes:
  esdatavm1:
    driver: local
  esdatavm2:
    driver: local
  esdatavm3:
    driver: local
networks:
  esvmnet:
```

But elasticsearch cannot go up, I receive these warning messages:

```
[2018-02-17T17:40:12,751][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12, reason=Cannot allocate memory
[2018-02-17T17:40:12,753][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
[2018-02-17T17:40:12,753][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 65536, hard limit: 65536
[2018-02-17T17:40:12,753][WARN ][o.e.b.JNANatives         ] These can be adjusted by modifying /etc/security/limits.conf, for example: 
    # allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall
    elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
    elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
```

and after that elastic die:

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked
[2018-02-17T17:40:26,490][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [F8VD2bv] stopping ...
```

Should I set the ulmits like said in warning?
In boot2docker I haven't any /etc/security/limits.conf where should I set that option?

Could someone help me?
Thanks a lot.
Regards.

Comment: Please correct the question with the proper error. This is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is different. I have tried replicating in my machine with single node.

Issue as follows

> [o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [4qfUlP0] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
>   ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
>   [1]: memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked

Just uncomment the line in Environment

```
- bootstrap.memory_lock=true
```

Else read the Elastic docs clearly regarding the environment variables.

Comment: bootstrap.memory_lock=true is not commented. I cannot set ulimit in compose because ulimits option is ignored with compose file version 3 and stack deploy